# Password-less auth using Auth0 and Twilio

Tags: authentication, sms, twilio, auth0, password-less

I'm building an app using password-less authentication using Auth0.com and there is a way for Anomaly Detection but seems like it is only for email auth using accounts. Is there a way to control the number of sms's sent using twilio.com to a certain phone number in a certain period of time so the user wont abuse the use of the service.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out today that after a lot of login attempts using Auth0 password-less authentication that user account was blocked.
[image]

Comment: Even thought it is still sending the sms from twilio but blocking its validation. I still need a way to stop the sms abuse.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint (`https://[tenant].auth0.com/passwordless/start`) used to start a passwordless authentication process with SMS is rate limited. See the [documentation on rate limiting](https://auth0.com/docs/policies/rate-limits) to learn which HTTP response headers to check if you want to know the exact limits.

I just did a quick test and I got a limit of around 50 requests per minute on that endpoint, however, this is not user configurable and is also not per phone number. I believe it's per IP address, although I have not confirmed it.

You could also rely on Twilio usage triggers to either be notified of possible abuse attempts or even implement a web hook that the trigger would call to automatically disable SMS based passwordless authentication in Auth0 if you detect activity levels way beyond what you would normally expect.